# Can WinHttpGetIEProxyConfigForCurrentUser obtain proxy from WPAD

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, networking, proxy

I was able to obtain proxy data that was manually entered into proxy settings on my Windows machine (`Use a proxy server for your LAN` option was checked) but I'm wondering if `WinHttpGetIEProxyConfigForCurrentUser` will also set field `LPWSTR lpszProxy` in case when `Use automatic configuration script` or `Automatically detect settings` checkboxes are checked in this dialog:

[image: proxy settings]

If not, how to obtain address of the currently used proxy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will get that in `lpszAutoConfigUrl`.

`lpszAutoConfigUrl` is variable of the structure `WINHTTP_CURRENT_USER_IE_PROXY_CONFIG` that is parameter of `WinHttpGetIEProxyConfigForCurrentUser`

Documentation link.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winhttp/ns-winhttp-winhttp_current_user_ie_proxy_config

Code used for a quick test:

```
WINHTTP_CURRENT_USER_IE_PROXY_CONFIG pProxyConfig;
pProxyConfig.fAutoDetect = TRUE;
WinHttpGetIEProxyConfigForCurrentUser(&pProxyConfig);
```

Comment: But will I get an url of autoconfig file or an url of the proxy from that file?

Comment: Tested it with "Use automatic configuration script".It gets the URL of the proxy from "Address" (disabled) textbox in the image you posted.

Answer (score 0):

WinHttpGetIEProxyConfigForCurrentUser() can be used to determine if both:

- "Automatically detect settings" is enabled (member 'fAutoDetect' of WINHTTP_CURRENT_USER_IE_PROXY_CONFIG structure) and
- "Automatic configuration script" is set (member 'lpszAutoConfigUrl' of WINHTTP_CURRENT_USER_IE_PROXY_CONFIG structure)

However, to obtain the proxy address itself for particular endpoint, **WinHttpGetProxyForUrl()** should be used.
If you already have 'Automatic configuration script' read from IE Internet options, you may use it like this:

```
WINHTTP_AUTOPROXY_OPTIONS autoProxyOptions= {0};
WINHTTP_PROXY_INFO proxyInfo= {0};

PCWSTR endpointUrl = <URL, that you need proxy for>;
autoProxyOptions.lpszAutoConfigUrl = <auto config address obtain from WINHTTP_CURRENT_USER_IE_PROXY_CONFIG>;
.
.    //set suitable autoProxyOptions flags
.

if (!WinHttpGetProxyForUrl(hSession, endpointUrl, &autoProxyOptions, &proxyInfo))
{
    GetLastError();
}
```